# Prevent Image from resizing div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to edit the parent divs and the image itself using css such as overflow: hidden, Object-fit: contain, max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;. What does work with my code is making the image a background image for the pic div and setting it to contain. Is there something I am missing on how to have the image inside the div without making it expand past the parent div? From my understanding it has to do with me using flexbox, probably wrong, with the name div making the contain div extend further down.

```js
function start(){
  var aa = document.getElementById("name");
  var ab = document.getElementById("charname");
  var ac = document.getElementById("prefs");
  var ad = document.getElementById("sliders-clearfix");
  var ae = document.getElementById("pref-sliders");
  aa.append(ab);
  ac.append(ad, ae);
}
```

```css
html, body, .profile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-flow: column;
  border: 5px inset blue;
}
div {
  display: flex;
}
.border{border: 5px inset blue;}
img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}
#name{width: 100%;}
#contain{height: 100%; width: 100%; flex-flow: row;}
#pic {height: 100%; width: 50%;}
#content{height: 100%; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="charname">Rage</h1>
<div class="profile">
<div id="name" class="border">
</div>
<div id="contain" class="border">
  <div id="pic" class="border">
    <img onload="start()" src="https://i.imgur.com/6LRFBk8.png">
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="border">
    <div id="prefs" class="border">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sliders-clearfix" class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="pref-sliders" class="show-p-only"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is css issue. Just try with which css works, according to the css framework or custom css you are using.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm trying. Seems that my issue is centered around my lack of understanding how flexbox works with images and divs. I might just have to re-write the code in another style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent div a px or rem or vh for height instead of percentage. Thats it.

`.border { border: 5px inset blue; height: 200px !important; }`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to work either. It doesn't look like it changes anything for the image as it still pushes outside the divs.

Comment: Make sure you give the image a height not max-height but height. It worked for me its weird it doesnt work for you though. Im gonna try one more time.

Comment: I think you didnt put important for whatever pixel your giving to the parent which is in the class border and its overwritten by another classes given height. You can check the answer I added a code.

Comment: I changed the max-height and max-width of the css img to height: 100% and width 100% but it's still having the same effect. I'm noticing it will look ok full screened but if i open the inspect elements it will push the picture outside the div. Also which div should I try making the height using vh/

Comment: I added the comment try that one then notify me with the result :)

Comment: Ok. So adding the height in px to the parent does in fact contain the picture. Is there a way for it to do that by filling the height of the containing divs?

Comment: Then you have to give the parent of the parent px or vh or rem height. For some reason percentage doesnt go well in this case with flex. If I got what you mean correctly?

Comment: Try adding height in px to contain class. Please notify me if its what you wanted. Thanks

Comment: Hey! Yea it actually works with that. Seems the issue is indeed the div not having a px height set. Once I changed the pic div height to px it contained the image. Thank you for the help.